# How to determine which dynamically loaded library causes memory leak

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 (C++) and am running into some memory leaks.
As I am working with several dlls, I was wondering if it was possible to see which dll allocates how much memory.

Comment: Does not `MSVC` provide profiler tools? Even `QtCreator` does that.

Comment: Memory is a process resource, it isn't "owned" by a module.  Most memory leak diagnostic utilities try to capture the stack trace of the allocation to help the programmer fix the cause, should make this obvious.  Umhd.exe on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 has great profiling tools (better than Visual Studio 2013) so if you can, switch to that, otherwise [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can do what you need. To see the heap sizes check the `View -> Show Lower Pane` and check `View -> Lower Pane View -> DLLs` and then when you click on a process the lower pane will show all the loaded DLLs. Then you can use `Select Columns` on the lower pane column header to display the private bytes. Example screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()

Though it works only in Debug Version

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite tools for memory allocation analysis is MemTrack:
http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html

It is very easy to set up and use and provides detailed breakdowns of memory/ blocks allocated per class.